# Inline elements not aligning

Tags: html, css, alignment

I got these share buttons from simplesharebuttons.com. I added a more button that will eventually be used to unhide less popular social media icons on smaller screens, but it's not lining up with the rest of the buttons and I can't figure out what the problem is.

http://jsfiddle.net/WLSqw/41/

```
#share-buttons img {
    width: 35px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    display: inline;
}

#more {
    width: 35px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    background: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 35px;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create an image with à link, as other button ? or add a float:left; to #more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, being an `inline-block` element, all you need for your `#more` is:

```
vertical-align: top;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WLSqw/61/)**

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left;` to the links and that button

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WLSqw/54/)

Comment: I don't think I can use `float:left` because at the mobile breakpoint, the icons need to be centered horizontally.